# Does the trivial character always show up as a weight?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group, $T$ a subtorus of $G$ of dimension $\geq 1$.  Let $\mathfrak g$ be the Lie algebra of $G$.  Then the Ad operator $$\textrm{Ad } : G \rightarrow \textrm{GL}(\mathfrak g)$$ is a rational representation of $G$, and the inclusion $T \subseteq G$ induces a rational representation of $T$.  Since $T$ is a torus, we know there exist characters $\chi_1, ... , \chi_t$ of $T$, and subspaces $V_i$ of $\mathfrak g$, such that $\mathfrak g$ is the direct sum of the $V_i$, and $\textrm{Ad}$ has the effect $$\textrm{Ad }x(v) = \chi_i(x)v$$ for all $x \in T, v \in V_i$.  The characters $\chi_i$ are called the weights of $T$ in $\mathfrak g$.  Now just as $T$ acts on $G$ by conjugation, $T$ also acts on $\mathfrak g$ by the Ad operator.  And one can show (5.4.7 in Springer), that fixed points correspond to fixed points via the Lie algebra.  In other words, $$\mathscr L(Z_G(T)) = \{ X \in \mathfrak g : \textrm{Ad }x(X) = X, \textrm{ for all } x \in T\}$$ Since $T \subseteq Z_G(T)$, $Z_G(T)$ has dimension $\geq 1$, hence $\mathscr L(Z_G(T))$ is a nonzero subspace.  It appears that $\mathscr L(Z_G(T))$, given the above description and the fact that it is nonzero, coincides with the weight space corresponding to the trivial character.  This seems to show that the trivial character **must** show up as one of the weights $\chi_1, ... , \chi_t$.

Is this correct?  If so, is there a more obvious or intuitive reason why this is true?

Comment: Because $\mathfrak{g}$ contains $\mathfrak{t}=\text{Lie}(T)$. And the conjugation action of $T$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ restricts to the conjugation action of $\mathfrak{t}$. But, $T$ is abelian, so its conjugation action on its Lie algebra is trivial. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, thanks very much.  So if $\chi$ is the trivial character, then since the conjugation map $T \rightarrow T$ is the identity, so is $\textrm{Ad }x$ as a map $\mathfrak t \rightarrow \mathfrak t$.  This shows that $$\mathfrak t \subseteq \{ X \in \mathfrak g : \textrm{Ad }(x)X = \chi(x)X, \textrm{ for all } x \in T\}$$ with $\mathfrak t \neq 0$.  Thus $\chi$ must be a weight vector.  But, can that inclusion above be a strict inclusion?

Comment: (my guess would be no?  I think $Z_G(T)$ is connected, so equality is equivalent to saying that the inclusion $T \subseteq Z_G(T)$  is an equality.)

Comment: As long as $T$ is a maximal torus, then no, it can't. This follows essentially from the fact that $Z_G(T)=T$ in this case. Thus, when one looks a the weight decomposition of $T$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ it's of the form $\displaystyle \mathfrak{t}\oplus\bigoplus_{\alpha}\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ with $\alpha\ne 0$. This is the beginning of root theory (as you likely already no). Of course, if $T$ is a non-maximal torus then (of course, we're working over $k=\overline{k}$ for convenience) then one can put $T$ inside a maximal torus $T'$ in which one gets that the character space for the trivial chara

Comment: character is $\mathfrak{t}'=\text{Lie}(T')$ as one might expect.